# Quickest way to change key name in nested json?

Tags: javascript, json

I have json that looks like this

```
const myJson = [
  {

  "title":"1. Lockdown Population by Loan (186006)",
  children:[
     {
        title:"1.1 Previous (191225)",
        "firstLevelSubNodes:[
              { 
                title:"1.1.1 Roll forward (178260)" ,
                "firstLevelSubNodes":[{ 
                  title:"1.1.1.1 Roll forward (178260)"
                  }]
              }
        ],
        "secondLevelSubNodes":[
             title:"1.2.1 Bounce forward (178260)" ,
                "firstLevelSubNodes":[{ 
                  title:"1.2.1.1 Dash forward (178260)",
                    "firstLevelSubNodes":[{ 
                     title:"1.2.1.1.1 Skip forward (178260)",
                  }]
                  }]
        ],
        "thirdLevelSubNodes":[
        ],
        "fourthLevelSubNodes":[

        ]
     }         
  ],
  }
]
```

Everywhere you see the word xxxLevelSubNodes it needs to say the word "children" like below.

```
 const myJson = [
     {

  "title":"1. Lockdown Population by Loan (186006)",
  children:[
     {
        title:"1.1 Previous (191225)",
        "children:[
              { 
                title:"1.1.1 Roll forward (178260)" ,
                "children":[{ 
                  title:"1.1.1.1 Roll forward (178260)"
                  }]
              }
        ],
        "children":[
             title:"1.2.1 Bounce forward (178260)" ,
                "children":[{ 
                  title:"1.2.1.1 Dash forward (178260)",
                    "children":[{ 
                     title:"1.2.1.1.1 Skip forward (178260)",
                  }]
                  }]
        ],
        "children":[
        ],
        "children":[
        ]
     }         
  ],
  }
]
```

I have tried to loop through but it renames the word with children however it overwrites the last key. Also it doesn't loop through the nested portion of the JSON.  I need it to remain in the exact same structure as above

```
const res = { firstLevelSubNodes: 'children', secondLevelSubNodes: 'children',

  thirdLevelSubNodes: 'children', fourthLevelSubNodes: 'children' }; 

 const object = JSON.parse(myJson);
    for (const k in res) {

      const newValue = res[k];

      object[newValue] = object[k];

      object[newValue].name = newValue;

      delete object[k];

    }
```

Comment: JSON cannot have two properties with same key

Comment: Maybe you can create one key `children` list and add all the xxxLevelSubNodes to it

Comment: I agree with @user7 but if you really wanted to, I would use `JSON.stringify()` and then use some regex with `string.replace()` You would get the result you're describing.

Comment: Do you want to merge the `children` arrays for everything that matches?

Comment: No merging. This represents a tree view in our app. The custom angular directive we use finds the word "children" and identifies it automatically  as a child node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the people who commented said, what you are asking for is not possible just because of the way JSON works.

you need to rethink what you are trying to do...
"This represents a tree view in our app. The custom angular directive we use finds the word "children" and identifies it automatically as a child node "

By that logic, there should be only 1 children property at each level that means that your json should look like:

```
let myJson = [
    {

        "title":"1. Lockdown Population by Loan (186006)",
        children:[
            {
                title:"1.1 Previous (191225)",
                "children":[
                   {
                        title:"1.1.1 Roll forward (178260)" ,
                        "children":[{
                            title:"1.1.1.1 Roll forward (178260)"
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        title: "1.2.1 Bounce forward (178260)",
                        "children": [{
                            title: "1.2.1.1 Dash forward (178260)",
                            "children": [{
                                title: "1.2.1.1.1 Skip forward (178260)",
                            }]
                        }]
                    },
                ],
            }
        ],
    }
];
```

If this is structure is true, what you really want to do is merge all the properties with a key that contains you format into the same array.

Of course you would want to do this recursively.

So its something like

```
function refactorJson(array) {
    for (var i =0; i< array.length; i++) {
        var obj = array[i];
        var newObj = {};
        newObj.title = obj.title;
        newObj.children = [];

        for (var property in obj) {
        console.log(property)
            if (property.contains('LevelSubNodes') || property === 'children') {
                var subObj = obj[property];
                var child = refactorJson(subObj);
                if (child) {
                    newObj.children.push(child);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return newObj;
}





var json =  [{
    "title": "1. Lockdown Population by Loan (186006)",
    "children": [{
        "title": "1.1 Previous (191225)",
        "firstLevelSubNodes": [{
            "title": "1.1.1 Roll forward (178260)",
            "firstLevelSubNodes": [{
                "title": "1.1.1.1 Roll forward (178260)"
            }]
        }],
        "secondLevelSubNodes": [{
            "title": "1.2.1 Bounce forward (178260)",
            "firstLevelSubNodes": [{
                "title": "1.2.1.1 Dash forward (178260)",
                "firstLevelSubNodes": [{
                    "title": "1.2.1.1.1 Skip forward (178260)"
                }]
            }]
        }],
        "thirdLevelSubNodes": [],
        "fourthLevelSubNodes": [

        ]
    }]
}];

var newJson = formatJson(json)
```

Comment: btw, your json had some other validity issues with it, so i added a test one that works

Comment: Also I noticed the return newObj variable exists outside of the loop it was created in

Comment: your code works but it is putting an extra [] bracket right after the children node. Do you know why it's doing that? The JSON isn't formatted correctly. It looks like "children": [ [ { } ] ] when it should be "children": [ { } ]

Comment: im not sure to what you are refereing to

{"title":"1. Lockdown Population by Loan (186006)","children":[{"title":"1.1 Previous (191225)","children":[{"title":"1.1.1 Roll forward (178260)","children":[{"title":"1.1.1.1 Roll forward (178260)","children":[]}]},{"title":"1.2.1 Bounce forward (178260)","children":[{"title":"1.2.1.1 Dash forward (178260)","children":[{"title":"1.2.1.1.1 Skip forward (178260)","children":[]}]}]}]}]}

this is what im getting, and the children is an array of objects not arrays as you are describing...
can you give me an example?